# Do I have to explicitly dispose my db connection object in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Do I **HAVE** to explicitly dispose of a db connection object using a dispose() method in my controller?

As the base Controller class already implements the IDisposable interface do I need to put a dispose() in my controller?

Or will the garbage collector do this for me anyway...what's the point if this is the case?

Comment: Let your IoC container do it.

Comment: What library are you using? You probably want to dispose it in Application_End but it really depends on the libray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
  ...
}
```

It is equivalent to:

```
try
{
   var connection = new SqlConnection()
    ...
}
finally
{
  connection.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should close it by using a "using" statement like Selman22 showed. The problem with waiting for the garbage collector to dispose of your connection after it falls out of scope is the garbage collector will only dispose of the connection when your application needs the memory. The garbage collector does not constantly clean up objects as they fall out of scope. If your application is not using a lot of memory, it could potentially be a while before that connection is closed.